# Pass a string as an argument

Tags: php, arrays, file, foreach, preg-match-all

I have a string which have grepped out of a php file, which was the arguments passed into a function, a var_dump of the string looks like this

```
'foo bar', ['name' => 'John, Smith']
```

and what I would like to do, is pass this to a function as two arguments. If there wasn't going to be a chance of a , in the array then I could explode the string and pass the two arguments to the function. But I can't and need to parse the string properly.

I can get around this by calling eval.

```
eval("myfunction({$string});");
```

which would work, but using eval is "risky". Is there a native method to pass a string to which would separate it into an array of arguments which I could then pass to my function?

I can't run this other php file, or change the code of it, I just want to grep out the arguments (which I have done) and then pass these arguments to my own function.

**Edit:**

So the string which is greped could be changed, my code for it would need to handle most ways of writing php arguments (no spaces after ',', or ' or "). It is always a string and an array, which is extracted from the text.

So it would need to support things like;

```
"foo",['name' => 'John, Smith']
"foo",[]
"foo, bar", [1,2 ,3]
```

Sort of like a reverse var_export... var_import :)

So, it seems like the best way might be to use eval... The code is "trusted" but still feels like a dirty way to do it, and thought there would be a method like parse_str or parse_url.

**Edit 2:**

So basically, twofiles. a.txt which is opened and regex grabs the params in a function. File b.php runs the regex, and then needs to handle the string to pass to a different function.

a.txt can't be changed to a php file. Need to run that code. (eval works as above).

```
File a.txt

<?php
   ... something ...
   $result = resetResult('foo bar', ['name' => 'John, Smith']);
   .. something ...
 ?>

 File b.php
 <?php
    $fileContents = file_get_contents('a.txt');
    preg_match_all('/resultResult\((.*?)\)/', $fileContents, $matches);
    foreach($matches[1] as $args) {
      // args = 'foo bar', ['name' => 'John, Smith'] but as a string. 
      // need to split args so 'foo bar' can be passed as first argument, and the array as the second argument..
      someFunction($args[0], $args[1]); 
    }
```

Comment: So your string won't always have a `,`?

Comment: We need more information on the format of the string that you have grepped out of the file. Will it remain that format each time you grep or could it be other formats? But to answer your question of "Is there a native method to pass a string to which would separate it into an array of arguments" the answer is no there is no single function you can call to do what you are asking.

Comment: no, would require a needlessly sophisticated regex, you're parsing php grammar at this point. if the infile is a dump of something else, is the whitespace before the `[` dofferent from the other whitespace?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here, _why_ do you need to do this?

Comment: You need a proper parser. You can use [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/token_get_all) to get the tokens of a given PHP source code.

Answer (score 1):

I did my best, but I'm still at beginning with PHP. There is no official function to convert an "array string" to array, so I tried to do a workaround with `json_decode()`.

Here is the code and a [fiddle](http://ideone.com/PelFn2)

```
<?
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$original = "'foo, bar', ['name' => 'John, Smith' , 'anotherKey' => 'another value']";
$str = get_string_between($original, "'", "'");
$arr = get_string_between($original, "[", "]");
$arr = json_decode(str_replace(' => ',':',str_replace('\'','"','{'.$arr.'}')), true);
var_dump($str);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Output

```
string(8) "foo, bar"
Array
(
    [name] => John, Smith
    [anotherKey] => another value
)
```

then call `yourFunc($str,$arr)`.

Of course my code could be improved, it's just a start. There will be a problem if an array value will contains `=>`, this should be fixed.

P.S.: `get_string_between()` was taken [here](http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/03/31/php-parse-a-string-between-two-strings/).

Comment: What if the string contains a `'` or the array contains another array?